# delegate event to serialize dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

[image: Fields]

I made a script that adds dynamic input to a div.
I want each time I entered an element on a dynamically created input to be push to a textarea as json string.
My problem is when ever I clicked add only the first two fields appeared to be serialized.

what I want is as shown below:

[image: dynamic content]

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Number of params
    var index = 0;

    function addParams() {
        var tmp_template = $('template').clone();
        var paramsDiv = $('#params');
        paramsDiv.append(tmp_template.html());
        $($('[class$="param-x"]')[index]).attr('name', 'param' + (index + 1));
        $($('[class$="value-x"]')[index]).attr('name', 'value' + (index + 1));
        index = index + 1;
    }

    addParams();

    $('#addParam').on('click', function() {
        addParams();
    });

    $('#params_div').on('click', "input", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $('#id_params').text(JSON.stringify($('#params_div :input'). serializeJSON()));
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="params_div" class="col-md-10">
            <div style="text-align:center">
                <label class="col-md-4">Param</label>
                <label class="col-md-6">Value</label>
            </div>
            <div id="params"></div>
            <!-- The template for adding new field -->
            <template>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control param-x" placeholder="Task" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control value-x" placeholder="Task" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="col-md-2">Add</label>
            <button id="addParam" type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton" name="add_field">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="id_params"></div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Do they all have the same name by any chance?

Comment: What is `serializeJSON()`? Are you using a third party plugin?

Comment: I mean using this library to convert inputs to json object https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I am using a third party jquery plugin.

Comment: There's no need for an external library, you can just use `JSON.parse` and `serializeArray()`, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5r80h3nm/

Comment: it works on jsfiddle but not in my django template.